# How to File Transfer client to Server?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, network-programming

i try to recieve a file from server but give me error on server.Start()

[image]

**ERROR : In a manner not permitted by the access permissions to access a socket was attempted to**
**How can i solve it?**

```
  private void btn_Recieve_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 13000;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.201");
            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            // Start listening for client requests.

            server.Start();
            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[277577];
            String data;
            data = null;
            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;
            i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, 277577);
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("GoodLuckToMe.jpg", FileMode.Create));
            writer.Write(bytes);
            writer.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Could you translate the exception message in English please?

Comment: ERROR: "In a manner not permitted by the access permissions to access a socket was attempted to." How can i change language turkish to English?

Comment: Google Translator : To access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a local address:

```
IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Loopback;
```

And make sure that the account your application is running under has sufficient privileges to open ports on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't read the exception, try change the different PORT number and check once. If the port is accessed by other process, you may get exception. I hope this is because of port.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an active firewall on the machine?